# Remove certain chars in-place

Tags: java

As far as I know, in C we can modify a char-array in-place and then append the `\0` to make the char-array shorter. I am wondering how that's done in Java.

Assume we want to remove the spaces from a char-array in Java.

```
char[] str = new String("cat love dogs").toCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] == ' ')
        str[i] = '';
}
```

This does not seem to work.

EDIT: I already know about built-in functions to replace some chars with another in a string. I am not asking that. **Curious to modify a char-array in-place with `O(1)` extra space.**

Comment: For what it's worth, this wouldn't work in C either. `''` is not a valid character literal in either C or Java, as character literals are, by definition, one character long.

Comment: Java string objects have a replace function that'll do exactly that.

Comment: @RichardBarker Curious how to implement that on a char-array without using built-in functions.

Comment: there is no possibility to change the length (or content) of an existing string without creating a new one. The \0 character does not terminate a string in java.

Comment: You may use StringBuilder class wich has charAt and deleteCharAt methods.

Comment: Do you want the `time complexity` of your whole program `O(1)`? it's not possible. Because if you iterate the `char array` the `time complexity` become `O(n)`.

Comment: @XO56 It is more important to say that `String` in java is not just array with characters, `String` is immutable.

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea You can't think of `String` in java like something similar to array of chars in C. You can't do in-place operations. `String` is immutable, so when you perform any operation you must create new `String`.

Comment: To be more specific, do you want to change the `array length`?

Answer (score 1):

well the best solution i can see is remove all spaces from your string first then get the chars from it :

```
 String myString = new String("cat love dogs").replaceAll("\\s+", ""); 
     // \\s+ is the regex for sapces 
    // myString becomes => catlovedogs
 char[] str = myString.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

As String is immutable you may use a StringBuilder class:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("cat love dogs");

for(int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        if(sb.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            i--;
        }
    }

char[] str = sb.toString().toCharArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

Now as far as space is concerned String class in Java is immutable!

Thus you cannot do anything in place there.

But you can use StringBuilder which is immutable.

Code:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("cat love dogs");
for(int i = 0; i < stringBuilder.length(); i++) {
    if (sb.charAt(i) == ' ')
        sb.deleteCharAt(i);
}
char[] str = stringBuilder.toString().toCharArray();
```

Or if you want to do it just using the char array itself its not possible as char arrays are not dynamic by themselves.

But here is what you could do:

```
char[] str = new String("cat love dogs").toCharArray();
int last = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] == ' '){
        str = ArrayUtils.remove(str, i);
    }
}
System.out.println(new String(str));
System.out.println(new String(str).length());
```

Output:

```
catlovedogs
11
```

For for this you need to import `org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils`

If you are not concerned about space:

In Java we can just set the character value to 0!

Here is the modified code:

```
char[] str = new String("cat love dogs").toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] == ' ')
        str[i] = 0;
}
System.out.println(new String(str));
```

Here is the output:

```
catlovedogs
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way to do this is by creating a duplicate array of chars, where you copy every character besides the spaces and then return the new array. Here is how the code might look like:

```
        char[] str = new String("cat love dogs").toCharArray();
        List<Character> duplicate = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if(str[i] != ' ') {
                duplicate.add(str[i]);
            }
                
        }
```

it's better to use ArrayList because you don't really know the final size of the array and this way you can go only as big as needed.

Comment: Why are you using ArrayList? Yes maybe  now you don't  have spaces and maybe that is what you want. But question was about doing operations on `String` in java in-place and with complexity `O(1)`. What is important to mention first in answer is fact that `String` is **immutable**.